# apache and node on the same server reserve ips?

Tags: apache, node.js, ip

I'm trying to install nodejs and apache on the same server following this:

https://gist.github.com/754303

Step 2 says:

> From the WHM cPanel, find the menu
>   item Service Configuration, select
>   Apache Configuration and then click on
>   Reserved IPs Editor.

I don't have cPanel. What's the equivalent manual configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it enough to edit your httpd.conf and edit the following line:

`Listen a.b.c.d:80`